# How to stop Vim from scrolling when splitting vertically

Tags: vim, scrolling

#### The problem

Somehow on this box every time I split a window (`^W v` or `:vs`) the original pane scrolls in such a way that my cursor is exactly `scrolloff=5` from the top.

I have tried to remove all `~/.vim*` and `/etc/vim*` files but no dice. Even a `aptitude purge vim` followed by a `rm -rf /usr/share/vim/ /etc/vim*` didn't change anything.

*Note: This seems to be specific to a certain Vim version since I do
not have this on my other boxes with the same `.vimrc`.*

---

#### Versions

- Vim: 7.3
- Ubuntu: 11.04

Comment: Just want to add that I am having the same problem during vertical splits and don't know how to debug any further.  Vim: 7.2, RHEL: 6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by Vim not knowing the window size the first time. After the first time it works just fine.

So to work around this issue, I have added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Little hack to fix the split/scroll problem 
tabnew
bwipeout
```

Comment: this actually causes another bug within the status bar.... not worth it IMO

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug, fixed in Vim 7.3, patch 084.

If you type (in a console/konsole/terminal/gnome-terminal...)

```
vim --version | head
```

you'll be able to see the version and patchlevel of your current vim/gvim.

You can also do this from within Vim itself:

```
:version
```

it'll paginate for you and you can read the version and patchlevel in the top of the first screen.

Comment: I would assume my version is new enough: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:22:36)
Included patches: 1-429`

Comment: Yup.  Bummer!  I'll keep this issue in mind, maybe I'll come across something.

Comment: Really odd... I remember seeing my system do the 'unexpected scroll when splitting window', like you describe, a few weeks ago. But now I can't reproduce it at all.  And all within Vim v7.3.300+.  I've upgraded at least once, now sitting at `v7.3 p547`.   Very odd.  Hmm, does it only do it on certain file TYPES?  MOAR TESTING!  {Grin}

Comment: Hrm... now that you mention it, I cannot reproduce it on all of my machines. I know I had the problem in the past but not anymore. The machine where I have the problem (with all filetypes, even when opening an empty buffer) is using this version: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jun 25 2011 09:43:11)
Included patches: 1-411` (Centos 6)

Comment: Glad to know I'm not going crazy (again!).  Ah, the fix was 7.3.84, that machine is 7.2.411..

Comment: FYI: I'm on the latest version of Macvim (Snapshot 65) which includes patches 1-646 and this is still very much present.

Comment: On Vim 7.4.729 here... same problem.  This is on Arch Linux if it matters.